# InnerJoin with Doctrine2 (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2 (~ 1 week). I have a manyToOne on the BudgetData Entity that joins the id of the Entity BudgetDescription.
I created a SQL query that I want to replicate for Doctrine :

```sql
SELECT d, e
FROM BudgetData d
INNER JOIN BudgetDescription e 
ON d.budgetDescription_id = e.id
```

BudgetData table :
id, year, value, budgetDescription_id (FK)

BudgetDescription table :
id, descriptionName

What I tried so far :

```php
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:BudgetData');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $dataQuery = $qb->select('d, c')
                    ->innerJoin('c.id', 'c', Join::ON, 'd.budgetDescription_id = c.id')
                    ->getQuery();

    $dataQuery = $dataQuery->getArrayResult();
```

Any idea how I can do the SQL query but in DQL ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

if you have a relation in your BudgetDataEntity called budgetDescription with an attribute $budgetDescription, in the BudgetDataRepository you could do :

```
    public function myInnerJoin()
    {

           $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f') 
                ->select('f','g')
                ->innerJoin('f.budgetDescription', 'g'); 

           return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

and in controller

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:BudgetData');
$result = $repository->myInnerJoin();
```

That is my guess

Comment: Not working at all... I think there is something I misstyped somewhere on the query. I don't know. Is everything alright on my first post ? (unless the DQL)

Comment: Alright, I had a type on my controller. What I did is :

Comment: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->createQuery("SELECT d.year, d.value, e.descriptionName FROM MainBundle:BudgetData d INNER JOIN MainBundle:BudgetDescription e WITH d.category = e.id");

$newQuery = $qb->getArrayResult();

Comment: This is completely superfluous. If you defined your associations correctly, Doctrine will manage the relationships between these entities for you. You don't need to create a custom query to simply get the associated entity. You would need to create a custom query if, for instance, you wanted to find a `BudgetData` entity based on some `BudgetDescription` property value (say like BudgetDescription.id = 3).

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to leverage the benefits of the Doctrine ORM. In a nutshell, create entity classes with the proper associations defined and then, as necessary, create custom query methods in the entity's repository class to do your lookups. Example:

#### The BudgetData entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MainBundle\Entity\BudgetDescription;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="budget_data")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Repository\BudgetDataRepository")
 */
class BudgetData
{
    // properties here

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BudgetDescription")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $budgetDescription;

    ...

    /**
     * Set budgetDescription
     *
     * @param BudgetDescription $budgetDescription
     * @return BudgetData
     */
    public function setBudgetDescription(BudgetDescription $budgetDescription)
    {
        $this->budgetDescription = $budgetDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get budgetDescription
     *
     * @return BudgetDescription
     */
    public function getBudgetDescription()
    {
        return $this->budgetDescription;
    }
}
```

#### The BudgetDescription entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="budget_description")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BudgetDescription
{
    // properties here
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")

     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

Now Doctrine will manage this association for you so that all you need to do to get the `BudgetDescription` entity from `BudgetData` is to call the `getBudgetDescription()` method of a `BudgetData` instance, like this:

```
$budgetData = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:BudgetData')->findOneById(3);
$budgetDescription = $budgetData->getBudgetDescription();
```

And voila. In the above example, Doctrine retrieves a `budget_data` row with ID=3 in your database and hydrates a `BudgetData` entity with that data. And then when you call the `getBudgetDescription()` method, it fetches the associated row in the `budget_description` table and hydrates a `BudgetDescription` entity. You can eliminate that second look up by using `fetch="EAGER"` in your association annotation. By default though, Doctrine lazy loads data so it only loads what you need.

I hope this helps.

p.s. I would recommend prefixing your primary and foreign key's with the names of the tables. So in the example above, your `budget_data` table would have a foreign key `budget_description_id` and your `budget_description` table would have a primary key `budget_description_id`. There are many good reasons for doing this not the least of which is clarity of associations between tables.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple query. The following code works, but if you have any other (better) solution, I would love to have it.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->createQuery("SELECT d.year, d.value, e.descriptionName FROM MainBundle:BudgetData d INNER JOIN MainBundle:BudgetDescription e WITH d.category = e.id");

$newQuery = $qb->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: There's definitely a better solution. Based on the comments thus far, it looks like you may not have the associations in your entities defined properly. Can you post those associations in your BudgetData and BudgetDescription entity classes?

Comment: BudgetData has a oneToMany reference, as I said before, it references "description" to "descriptionName" of the BudgetDescription Entity.

Comment: In your original post, you said `I have a manyToOne on the BudgetData Entity that joins the id of the Entity BudgetDescription`. In your comment above, you expressed a completely different association, and in the SQL statement yet another different association. Your problem is how you're ***actually*** defining the associations in your entities.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to post your actual schema and your actual entity class snippets so we can see what you're actually attempting to do, but lacking that, I'll post an example below for you to illustrate how it can/should be done based on the SQL statement you stated works for you.